# Remove index.php from URLs in Kohana 2.x

Tags: php, kohana

I want to configure Kohana 2.x to have links in this format:

```
http://localhost/mysite/web/admin/support
```

instead of this:

```
http://localhost/mysite/web/admin/index.php/support
```

I removed the `index.php` from the config.php file `( $config['index_page'] = '';)` and I added the following line in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

If you hover above a link you can see that the links are like I wanted them but there is always this error:

> Not Found
>   The requested URL /mysite/web/admin/support was not found on this server

I don't know how to change the configuration like I want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write following code in htaccess::

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(application|modules|system) - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

you can also change the config.php file to:

> `$config['index_page'] = '';`

another one try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^index\.php index.php%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

try more solution then see
[How to set up .htaccess for Kohana correctly, so that there is no ugly "index.php/" in the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966429/how-to-set-up-htaccess-for-kohana-correctly-so-that-there-is-no-ugly-index-php)
see also following tuts::
http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/tutorials/clean-urls

Comment: Now it gets another message:

       The requested URL /index.php/support was not found on this server.

I dont have pear installed..

Comment: You need to change the rewritebase to include the directory kohana is stored in. `RewriteBase /mysite/web/admin/`