# .htaccess in local apache directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, ubuntu, apache2

I'm using kohana framework in on ubuntu using apache2. It requires a modification to .htaccess which was said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5157702/400861). I cannot find this file in ubuntu so I think I remember that we can create our own .htaccess that is local to the project.

My file structure is: `localhost/src/application/{kohana framework}`

When I create the htaccess file here: `localhost/src/application/.htaccess` for some reason it still doesn't work well with the rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(application|modules|system) - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

1. Is this possible? Does the .htaccess in that directory work for the files in that and sub-directories?
2. If it does, how can I write a simple test to make sure its working and its not the code that is the problem?

Comment: You have not shown the .htaccess file content.

Comment: While used to support a programming framework, this is fundamentally a question about server administration, and as such, is probably a better fit on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 1):

1) A `htaccess` is recursive by default

2) You can put some random garbages caracters in `htaccess`, then call you web page. You should see an `error 500` that attest that the `htaccess` is used. That done, you can add your real configuration to finish.

Comment: i put random garbage in it and the page loaded fine. can you look at where I put the file and tell me if it should work?

Comment: Your **htaccess** should be inside the [Apache DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/fr/mod/core.html#documentroot) and you need to load some apache modules : `a2enmod mod_authn_file mod_authz_groupfile`. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/howto/htaccess.html